# How to handle NullReferenceExceptions without using try/catch

Tags: c#, exception

I have a code like this:

```
string fileLocation = Request.Form["FileName"].ToString(); 

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLocation))
{                          
    var deleteFile = fileLocation.Split('\\')[1];
    var pathe = Path.Combine(uploadPath, deleteFile;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathFile))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(pathFile);
    }
}
```

Usually if i don't select a file, `Request.Form["FileName"].ToString()` will return a SystemNullException which I intend to set it as null.

Is there anyway i can do it without using try catch?

Comment: something like `string  fileLocation = Request?.Form["FileName"]?.ToString();`

Comment: Some part of `Request.Form["FileName"].ToString()` will be null.  Find out which bit by adding a breakpoint and generating the condition, then put in a specific check, e.g., `if (Request != null)`, or `if (Request.Form["FileName"] != null)` before the `.ToString()` call.

Answer (score 3):

If `Request.Form["FileName"]` returns null then you can't do `.ToString()`.

So you can use null propagator to get around this:

```
Request.Form["FileName"]?.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check before applying `.ToString`.

```
var result = Request.Form["FileName"];
if(result != null)
{
    string fileLocation = result.ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileLocation))
    {
        var deleteFile = fileLocation.Split('\\')[1];
        var pathe = Path.Combine(uploadPath, deleteFile;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(pathFile))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(pathFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would prefer if(result == null) return to reduce indentation. Or use null propagtor